# Angular 4 checkbox set programmatically

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I have seen similar questions about this but I still do not get it.
I have a component witch gets list of items `Array<{id: number, name: string}>` and a list of "checked" items `Array<number>`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'check-list',
    template: `
    <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let item of list">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" 
                type="checkbox" 
                [checked]="checked.includes(item.id)"
                (change)="onChange.emit({id: item.id, value: $event.target.checked})">
            {{ item.name }}
        </label>
    </div>
    `
})

export class CheckListComponent {
    @Input() list: CheckListItem[];
    @Input() checked: number[];

    @Output() onChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() { }
}
```

If I update the "checked" list the rendered checkbox list gets updated as well, but if I click some of the checkboxes and then updates the "checked" list it does not render as I expected.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/YSItU48QflE4GZbj58Ev?p=preview

Click on the two buttons in the plunker and it works as I expect, the checkboxes updates according to the "checked" list. But if I click the "item 2" and then click reset, it does not clear "item 2".

I have also tried using `[ngModel]` and `[attr.checked]`.
The reason I do not want to use `[(ngModel)]` is that I also have a `@Output()` which triggers a server request and then if that fails the checkbox should update or not. I'm using `ngrx` for states.

**UPDATE:**

So I was not clear enough in my question that I'm using Redux/ngrx and the list sent in to my check-list-component should not be mutated directly by the component itself. I have updated the component to send back outputs on changes

Heres the new plnker: https://plnkr.co/edit/lMouWapI2lb9U6mS9YMy?p=preview

**UPDATE 2:**

So the problem I have is that click/check will send an update to a server, and if that fails I want the checkbox to be reset to the previous state.
I have added a random bool if the server request is a success or not.
Maybe I'm using the wrong type of implementation ide for this.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/nGyS8oYWVzzRULgzcDQV?p=preview

Comment: Did below answer resolve your issue?

Comment: Well.. your solution work for the case I posted. I have added a new plunker

Comment: Maybe, you should have added details initially, or had added new questiuon after closing this. Check this [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

you need to update checked array in the `check-list` compoennt as well when ever check is changed,

**Check List**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'check-list',
    template: `
    <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let item of list">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" 
                type="checkbox" 
                [checked]="checked.includes(item.id)"
                (change)="onChange.emit({id: item.id, value: $event.target.checked})">
            {{ item.name }}
        </label>
    </div>
    `
})    
export class CheckListComponent {
    @Input() list: CheckListItem[];
    @Input() checked: number[];
    
    @Output() onChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() { }
}
```

**App**

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <check-list [list]="list" [checked]="checked" 
        (onChange)="updateChecked($event)"></check-list>
      <button (click)="setFirstChecked()">Set First Checked</button>
      <button (click)="resetChecked()">Reset Checked</button>
    </div>
   `
})
export class App {      
  ....
  updateChecked($event) {
    // This will be handled in Redux/ngrx...
    if ($event.value) {
      this.checked.push($event.id);
    } 
    else {
      this.checked = this.checked.filter((i) => i !== $event.id);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Updated the [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/ob6FAjsxfmHkJOhd4lCz?p=preview)

Comment: Nice dynamic way :)

Comment: @Swoox, Thanks.. :)

Comment: Was wonder if put more buttons, if it would work. But it did very nice.

Comment: Hi, well I will update my question, but the state I'm sending in to my checklist is a Redux immutable state so the component should not update it itself but send back an Event

Comment: @Korven, updated answer and [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ob6FAjsxfmHkJOhd4lCz?p=preview) too, updated yours code only , in your Plunker you are checking `$event.checked` you should be checking `$event.value` as the emitted object has `value`. Cheers!!