# Prevent check of checkbox until function has been called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

We are using AngularJS, and we require to run a function that determines whether or not the checkbox the user clicked on is actually checked. I have tried to pass `$event` on `ngChange`, but discovered it is unable to pass the `$event` object. The reason I want to access the `$event` object is so I could prevent the default behaviour until the required function has been called.

The code is as follows (does not include the code where I attempted to pass `$event` as it didn't work):

```
<label for="specificCase">
    Yes
    <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        name="specificCase" 
        data-ng-click="specificCase.no = false; specificCase.unsure = false;" 
        data-ng-model="specificCase.yes" 
        data-ng-change="$ctrl.specificCaseCheck('yes', specificCase.yes)">
</label>
<label for="notSpecificCase">
    No
    <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        name="notSpecificCase" 
        data-ng-click="specificCase.yes = false; specificCase.unsure = false;" 
        data-ng-model="specificCase.no" 
        data-ng-change="$ctrl.specificCaseCheck('no', specificCase.no)">
</label>
```

**controller**

```
function specificCaseCheck(value, boolean) {

     //HERE I WANT TO PREVENT THE DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR OF THE CHECKBOX CHECKING

    vm.optionSelected = !boolean ? false : true;
    vm.caseSpecific = value == 'yes' && boolean ? true : false;
}
```

**Question**

How do I keep the checkbox unchecked until I have run a function in the controller?

Comment: The purpose you are trying to achieve sounds a bit obscure, do you want to run a function when the user clicks the checkbox and "check it" only when the function has finished ?

Comment: Yes, so they can check it (click it), but until the function runs, the checkbox won't show as being checked

Comment: something like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017793/angular-2-checkbox-preventdefault

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to prevent default behavior but dont have the `event` you can follow the approach of this question [Angular 2 Checkbox preventDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36017793/angular-2-checkbox-preventdefault)

Basically you need to `return false` in your event handler to prevent the default behavior of "checking the checkbox when is clicked" then you can click it programatically

For that you can check this question [Angular 4 checkbox set programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46000515/angular-4-checkbox-set-programmatically)